# How to achieve true multi tenancy in nifi?

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi, multi-tenant

I have setup user authentication using ldap for nifi. Now when I am able to add new users and achieve access restrictions to different users etc.

But still now I am not able to understand how to truly achieve multi-tenancy with nifi. For eg. when I add new users and to let them view the interface I give the policy to view the interface. But the user is still able to see all the components positions and connections even though not able to access them.

This is not true multi-tenancy as I understand because users should not be able to see things even though not accessible to them. The same is problem with the controllers. Users are able to view them but not access or edit. It is also not possible to create a admin just for a tenant.

Is there anyway we can truly achieve this in nifi?

Comment: you are talking about access restrictions to the application users, what aspect of multi-tenancy is this question?

Comment: The problem @Saravanan is that I have seen and gone through the Nifi apis and UI. Here what I understand from multi tenencey is acess restricted users but not in a way different clients should acess the system. Because with nifi what I could see is that multi tenancy means a lot like access restrictions. Every tenant uses the same root group and people with access to user interface can see all the processors on root process group but not any contents such as name. I was wondering how to get through this?

Comment: So your question is: can you restrict what users SEE in NiFi, not just what they can edit? You don't want group A to even SEE what group B is creating?

Comment: Exactly that is what needed

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that's possible currently

Comment: @Sdairs Even my research around this says that those feature doesn't exist in Nifi. It is built for multi-tenancy in a single organisation.

Comment: @pacman Are users without permissions still able to open process groups and view everything there? If not, you can define controllers and (in newer versions) parameter contexts at lower process group levels without them being visible from the root canvas.

Comment: @Cyrus are you saying that it is achievable with the newer versions of Nifi? I would probably have to workout and see if what you are saying is achievable